# Covariance, generic, UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a user control that contains an `ObservableCollection<Something>`. I learned that I cannot cast say `ObservableCollection<Tiger>` to `ObservableCollection<Animal>`. The solution I found was to add a helper class that handles all low level collection manipulation. My suspicion is that there is a more elegant solution and if so, maybe someone can point me into that direction.

See the code below that captures the problem and my solution. `Zoo` corresponds to the WPF UserControl. (Actually a zoo for one type od animal.) Ideally I would define it as `Zoo<T>` i.e. as a generic type but that would prevent me from using XAML. I need to define `Animals` as `object` in order assign to it.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
        List<Tiger> tigers = new List<Tiger>() { new Tiger() };
        zoo.Animals = tigers;
        zoo.Helper = new TigerHelper(tigers);

        Console.WriteLine(zoo.GetCount());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Animal { }
public class Tiger : Animal { }

public interface Helper { int GetCount(); }
public class TigerHelper : Helper
{
    private List<Tiger> tigers;
    public TigerHelper(List<Tiger> tigers) { this.tigers = tigers; }
    public int GetCount() { return tigers.Count; }
}

public class Zoo
{
    public object Animals { get; set; }
    public Helper Helper { get; set; }
    public int GetCount() { return Helper.GetCount(); }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at ItemsControl. It is a container element for all kinds of item objects. You don't need Generics.

Comment: The XAML in my UserControl consists of a TabControl. I would not know how I could leverage the ItemsControl.

Comment: A TabControl is an ItemsControl. Take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: Yep this is really a question for softwareengineering and not for stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than go all the way down to `object`, you can use [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist). This gives you access to most of the features of the list, but without the generics. For example, you can still access the `Count` property:

```
    public class Zoo
    {
        public IList Animals { get; set; }
        public Helper Helper { get; set; }
        public int GetCount() { return Animals.Count; }
    }
```